# How to get Field name

Tags: visualforce, api, fields

I have a VF page where admin can select fields which need to be displayed. And on an another Vf page i am getting the API name of all the selected fields in 1st Vf page. This much is working fine i want to display the Field label of all the API fields as header in column. Is their any way to get the field label using APIName. The fields which are displayed is on Vf page as Dynamically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can use

```
{!$ObjectType.SOBJECTNAME.fields.FIELDNAME.label}
```

eg

```
{!$ObjectType.Account.fields.Phone.label}
```

To iterate over all the field labels for Account

```
Map<String, SobjectField> fieldMap = Account.getsObjectType().getDescribe().Fields.getMap(); 
for(String f :  fieldMap.keySet())
System.debug(fieldMap.get(f).getDescribe().getLabel());
```

You can construct an API Name, Label Map and bind that in Visualforce.

Comment: yes but i have a list of api name where i cannot say that it is phone name etc

Comment: Added an Edit to retrieve field labels programatically. be mindful of the describe governor limit tho.